# Creating Custom Field: how to mix ImageField and ColorField?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I need a field that stores information about one or the followings:

- an image path if the field refers to a picture (like models.ImageField)
- a string that represents a color (**in format** *"rgb(245,30,46)"*) if the field refers to a color.

For details: I need to store information about a background that can be a picture or a color.

Should I make an inheritance from models.ImageField or from models.CharField? If the former then how can I provide correct tests of storing information to a database and retrieving the information from a database?

If you have the such example, please give me a link.

Comment: You really need to store path and color in one model field?

Comment: I think it's attractive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those data types (while technically both strings) are too different to sensibly store in the same column. You should merely use two fields, one for an image, the other for a color and make both optional (`blank=True`).

You can then override your model's `clean` method to force one or the other to be present:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    def clean(self):
        if not self.image and not self.color.strip():
            raise ValidationError('You must specify either an image or color')
```

Comment: Thank you, Chris, for a very good idea! But both are string-based as you told, so, may be I could create a field inherited from models.CharField? In any case thank you for the advice.

Comment: Yes, they're both string-based, but `FileField`s have a lot of infrastructure to them that would be hard, if not impossible, to factor out if the value is merely a color. You *could* simply use a `CharField`, but then you lose all that infrastructure in `FileField`, and would have to recreate it all (and account for future updates to file management in Django). The code would be a mess. It's just a bad idea all around.

Comment: Thank you! Rely on your experience.